# Creating a bootloader for STM32F051C8

Tags: stm32, bootloader

I need to design the hardware to load my custom programs into a [STM32F051C8T6 microcontroller](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00039193.pdf) and I'm not sure of which pins should be connected to what and I wouldn't like to do things wrong.

I've found some good information in the web about the software part, but not about the hardware part.

Comment: Have you read AN2606 from ST? There is a hardware requirements section in it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy aka, seems useful. It only talks about STM32F1xx and STM32F2xx, not about STM32F0xx, but it may work.

Comment: Another useful one might be [AN4065](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/DM00050074.pdf)

Comment: Or better yet, [AN2606](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00167594.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot, fm_andreas! There's the information I need. :)

Comment: BTW, I noticed there are 2 different AN2606... The one I downloaded first [https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/cortex_mx_stm32/Attachments/18225/AN2606.pdf] only talked about STM32F1 and F2 series. The one fm_andreas found talks about F0, F1, F3 and F4 series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with [schematics](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/layouts_and_diagrams/schematic_pack/stm32vldiscovery_sch.zip) of [STM32VLDISCOVERY](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM116/SC959/SS1532/PF250863).

The board comes with STM32F100RB and is cheap enough to experiment.